# How to calculate TF-IDF on grouped spark dataframe in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I have used Spark Api (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#tf-idf) for calculating TF IDF on a dataframe. What I am unable to do is to do it on grouped data using Dataframe groupBy and calculating TFIDF for each group and in the result getting single dataframe.

For Example for input

```
id |  category        | texts                           
 0 |  smallLetters    | Array("a", "b", "c")            
 1 |  smallLetters    | Array("a", "b", "b", "c", "a")  
 2 |  capitalLetters  | Array("A", "B", "C")
 3 |  capitalLetters  | Array("A", "B", "B", "c", "A)
```

Sample output for group by column "category"

```
id | category       | texts                           | vector
0  | smallLetters   | Array("a", "b", "c")            | (3,[0,1,2],[1.0,1.0,1.0])
1  | smallLetters   | Array("a", "b", "b", "c", "a")  | (3,[0,1,2],[2.0,2.0,1.0])
2  | capitalLetters | Array("A", "B", "C")            | (3,[3,4,5],[1.0,1.0,1.0])
3  | captialLetters | Array("A", "B", "B", "c", "A)   | (5, [3,4,2],[2.0,2.0,1.0])
```

Taking example from the spark website I am currently similar to this:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{CountVectorizer, CountVectorizerModel}

val df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
  (0, Array("a", "b", "c")),
  (1, Array("a", "b", "b", "c", "a"))
)).toDF("id", "words")

// fit a CountVectorizerModel from the corpus
val cvModel: CountVectorizerModel = new CountVectorizer()
  .setInputCol("words")
  .setOutputCol("features")
  .setVocabSize(3)
  .setMinDF(2)
  .fit(df)

// alternatively, define CountVectorizerModel with a-priori vocabulary
val cvm = new CountVectorizerModel(Array("a", "b", "c"))
  .setInputCol("words")
  .setOutputCol("features")

cvModel.transform(df).show(false)
```

Now the issue I am facing is how to calculate TF-IDF using the above code after doing a groupby operation on category.

Edit: I  want to define the Corpus as the grouped data. That is smallLetters is one corpus and capitalLetters is another, so that for TF-IDF calculations smallLetters corpus contains 2 documents and capitalLetters contains 2 documents.

Comment: Can you please share what you are trying to do? code example etc, that would be very helpful if you want to get an answer back.

Comment: After grouping the array should be merged and then compute on them TF-IDF? E.g : for smallletters : Array ("a", "b", "c","a", "b", "b", "c", "a")

Comment: No, they should can not be merged since I am also calculating IDF value at category level and the arrays are individual documents. So if we merge the array the IDF value will go wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure what you really want..  the key is to define what a 'document' is..  Is it (1) a single input row or is it (2) the result after grouping multiple rows?  In the first case, you perform IDF tranformation on the original rows and aggregate by joining multiple arrays to combine multiple documents word IDFs .  In the second case, you simply need to apply IDF transformation on the result of the grouping (with arrays combined) as suggested by dumitru

Comment: @MichelLemay for (1), if he performs IDF transform on all 4 original rows, then don't you think that all 4 documents will be considered to be in one big corpus, whereas he wants small and capital letters categories to be two different corpus.