# How to calculate TF-IDF of dataframe groups using PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark, tf-idf

My question is [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45676390/how-to-calculate-tf-idf-on-grouped-spark-dataframe-in-scala) to this but I am using PySpark and the question had no solution there.

My dataframe `df` is as follows, where `id_2` represents a document id and `id_1` represents the corpus they belong to:

```
+------+-------+--------------------+
|  id_1|   id_2|              tokens|
+------+-------+--------------------+
|122720| 139936|[front, offic, op...|
|122720| 139935|[front, offic, op...|
|122720| 126854|[great, pitch, lo...|
|122720| 139934|[front, offic, op...|
|122720| 126895|[front, offic, op...|
|122726| 139943|[challeng, custom...|
|122726| 139944|[custom, servic, ...|
|122726| 139946|[empowerment, chapt...|
|122726| 139945|[problem, solv, c...|
|122726| 761272|[deliv, excel, gu...|
|122728| 131068|[assign, mytholog...|
|122728| 982610|[trim, compar,...|
|122779| 226646|[compar, face, to...|
|122963|1019657|[rock, tekno...|
|122964| 134344|[market, chapter,...|
|122964| 134343|[market, chapter,...|
|122965|1554436|[human, resourc, ...|
|122965|1109173|[solut, hrm...|
|122965|2328172|[right, set...|
|122965|1236259|[hrm, chapter, st...|
+------+-------+--------------------+
```

How can I calculate TF-IDF of the documents for each corpus?

```
tf = hashingTF.transform(df)
idfModel = idf.fit(tf)
tfidf = idfModel.transform(tf)
```

-- for the given scenario, `tf` should work just fine as it is document specific but using `idf` like this considers all the documents belonging to a single corpus.

Comment: I think you have to craft something by yourself. 1. collect a list of `id_1`, 2. loop over this list and filter the df before you generate the tfidf for each model, 3. add the tfidf to a dictionary (key=id_1, value=model).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and this is the inefficient working solution. Any ideas on further improving this are appreciated.

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import HashingTF, IDF
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline

preProcStages = []

hashingTF = HashingTF()
idf = IDF() 
preProcStages += [hashingTF, idf]

pipeline = Pipeline(stages=preProcStages)

def compute_idf_in_group(df):
    model = pipeline.fit(df)
    data = model.transform(df)
    return data

def unionAll(*dfs):
    return reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, dfs)
    
resolved_groups = []
grouped_ids = list(set(df.select('id_1').rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()))
for id in grouped_ids:
    sub_df = df.filter(sf.col('id_1')==id)
    resolved_df = compute_idf_in_group(sub_df)
    resolved_groups.append(resolved_df)
    
final_df = unionAll(resolved_groups)
```